# How to filter df by column's value NOT in value list with Polars?

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

My last question about filter df by value list had a nice solution:
[How to filter df by value list with Polars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74856449/how-to-filter-df-by-value-list-with-polars)

But now I have inverse task.

I have a list with some int values: `black_list = [45, 87, 555]`
And I have df with some values in column cid1.

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "cid1": [45, 99, 177],
        "cid2": [4, 5, 6],
        "cid3": [7, 8, 9],
    }
)
```

How I can filter df by my `black_list` to result df contains only rows without blacklisted values in the "cid1" column?

I can't filter by some white_list according to the conditions of my task.

The code `.filter((pl.col("cid1").is_not(black_list))` not suitable.  I tried it but it get me an error `TypeError: Expr.is_not() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`and I don't catch another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `~` to get reversed Series of `bool` values

```py
df.filter(~col("cid1").is_in(black_list))
```

or you can use `.is_not()` to reverse `bool` values

```py
df.filter(col("cid1").is_in(black_list).is_not())
```

Comment: Thank you! All this variants is the solutions for me! Only not just 'col' but I print 'pl.col'

Comment: Oh, forgot about it. I always use `col` - it's a bit shorter)) (`from polars import col` after importing polars)